# MySQL pivot single row

Tags: mysql, sql

I've found a lot of questions to do this the other way but I can't solve it for this way.

Let's say I select one row from a table so I have the following:

```
A | B | C | D | E
------------------
 1| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

How can I pivot it in mysql to create something like:

```
r | c
-----
A | 1
-----
B | 2
-----
C | 3
-----
D | 4
-----
E | 5
```

which I then plan to join onto another table.

Is this possible to do?  How?  I can't think of any ways and I can't find an answer on google.

Thank you.

Comment: So you basically want to create a Pivot Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column names are fixed, you can use this

(Sample table)

```
create table so_tmp(a int, b int, c int, d int, e int);
insert into so_tmp select 1,2,3,4,5;
```

## select a,b,c,d,e from so_tmp;

Unpivot query:

```
select 'a' r, a c from so_tmp
union all
select 'b', b from so_tmp
union all
select 'c', c from so_tmp
union all
select 'd', d from so_tmp
union all
select 'e', e from so_tmp;
```